# PySpark - create multiple json files from dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have data in the following format, which is obtained from Hive into a dataframe:

```
date, stock, price
1388534400, GOOG, 50
1388534400, FB, 60
1388534400, MSFT, 55
1388620800, GOOG, 52
1388620800, FB, 61
1388620800, MSFT, 55
```

Where date is the epoch for midnight on that day, and we have data going back 10 years or so (800million+ rows).
My aim is to end up with a bunch of JSON files, one per stock, that would look like:

```
GOOG.json:
{
'1388534400': 50,
'1388620800': 52
}

FB.json:
{
'1388534400': 60,
'1388620800': 61
}
```

A naive way would be to get a list of unique stocks and then get a subset of the dataframe by filtering out only those rows for each stock but this seems overly naive and horribly inefficient.
Can this be done easily in Spark? I've currently got it working in native Python using PyHive, but due to the sheer volume of data, I'd rather have this done on a cluster/Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is quite straightforward. You can use a DataFrameWriter and use partitionBy - specify the column(s) to partition on (in your case it would be stock)

From the Pyspark documentation:

> df.write.partitionBy('year', 'month').parquet(os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(), 'data'))

For you this would be

```
df.write.partitionBy('stock').json(os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(), 'data'))
```

Note a few things:

- This will possibly need a lot of shuffling depending on how the Hive Tables are laid out.
- Even after the partitions you might end up with more than one file per partition depending on how many records there are in that partition. For e.g. 30% of the activity might be for GOOG and in that case the partition for GOOG will be much larger than others. You'll simply need to run a file catenation script for each partition if you run into that. The files in each partition, however, will still be for one single stock.

Comment: Thanks @RobS. I guess I should have mentioned this in the question itself, but I'd first like the data returned in a dict format, so I can run validations and handling of missing data - I've asked another question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932942/pyspark-create-dict-of-dicts-from-dataframe

Comment: You're probably better off doing all the validations and data cleaning in spark itself. The sparl Functions Module is excellent for the kind of stuff that you're talking about. Moving it from Hive to a local Dict and then back to the cluster is likely going to be much slower than running all the validations in parallel on the cluster.