# PySpark: create dict of dicts from dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have data in the following format, which is obtained from Hive into a dataframe:

```
date, stock, price
1388534400, GOOG, 50
1388534400, FB, 60
1388534400, MSFT, 55
1388620800, GOOG, 52
1388620800, FB, 61
1388620800, MSFT, 55
```

Where date is the epoch for midnight on that day, and we have data going back 10 years or so (800million+ rows).
I'd like to get a dictionary as follows:

```
{
'GOOG':
{
'1388534400': 50,
'1388620800': 52
}

'FB':
{
'1388534400': 60,
'1388620800': 61
}
}
```

A naive way would be to get a list of unique stocks and then get a subset of the dataframe by filtering out only those rows for each stock but this seems overly naive and horribly inefficient.
Can this be done easily in Spark? I've currently got it working in native Python using PyHive, but due to the sheer volume of data, I'd rather have this done on a cluster/Spark.

Comment: If you want that data structure, you're going to have to collect all of the data into local memory at some point. Sure you can do the aggregation in spark, but you're still going to lose the benefits of using spark. As far as I can tell, it's going to be the same as (or very similar to) using your PyHive solution. Perhaps this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Very possibly an XY problem. Here's the gist of what I'm trying to accomplish - I have values for data points taken every 30 minutes for the past 5 years, potentially 87k points per stock. I need this in the format specified - `{symbol: {epoch1: value1, epoch2: value2...}} ` as I have a routine that searches for missing datapoints and inserts null values, returning everything in a sorted json file that ultimately feeds into a visualization portal. I guess I could move the validation routine to Spark as well

Comment: Maybe an option would be to write out the data to a file in your specified format? That way the writes can be done in parallel (to multiple files) and it will be a lot more efficient than collecting the data.

Comment: @pault here's more details of the problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934614/handling-missing-data-in-pyspark - I'm doing things this way as there's a possibility of missing data that needs to be handled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spark 2.4 you can use `map_from_arrays` to build the date-value maps when aggregating values for each stock. Then it's just a matter of use `create_map` to use the ticker symbol as a key. This example uses `ChainMap` from python 3.4 to build the final dict structure as you described.

```
import json
from collections import ChainMap
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("example") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1388534400, "GOOG", 50),
    (1388534400, "FB", 60),
    (1388534400, "MSFT", 55),
    (1388620800, "GOOG", 52),
    (1388620800, "FB", 61),
    (1388620800, "MSFT", 55)]
).toDF("date", "stock", "price")

out = df.groupBy("stock") \
        .agg(
            map_from_arrays(
                collect_list("date"), collect_list("price")).alias("values")) \
        .select(create_map("stock", "values").alias("values")) \
        .rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x) \
        .collect()

print(json.dumps(dict(ChainMap(*out)), indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), sort_keys=True))
```

Which gives:

```
{                                                                               
    "FB": {
        "1388534400": 60,
        "1388620800": 61
    },
    "GOOG": {
        "1388534400": 50,
        "1388620800": 52
    },
    "MSFT": {
        "1388534400": 55,
        "1388620800": 55
    }
}
```

**However**, as you say you have a lot of data you probably don't actually want to create this dictionary in memory, so probably you would be better of splitting this up and writing the same dictionary structure into files for different partitions.

Let's do that by truncating the dates to the given month and writing seperate file for each month and for each stock:

```
out = df.groupBy(trunc(expr("CAST(date as TIMESTAMP)"), "month").alias("month"), df["stock"]) \
        .agg(
            map_from_arrays(
                collect_list("date"), collect_list("price")).alias("values")) \
        .select("month", "stock", create_map("stock", "values").alias("values"))

out.write.partitionBy("month", "stock").format("json").save("out/prices")
```

This gives you a structure like the following:

```
out
└── prices
    ├── _SUCCESS
    └── month=2014-01-01
        ├── stock=FB
        │   └── part-00093-3741bdc2-345a-488e-82da-53bb586cd23b.c000.json
        ├── stock=GOOG
        │   └── part-00014-3741bdc2-345a-488e-82da-53bb586cd23b.c000.json
        └── stock=MSFT
            └── part-00152-3741bdc2-345a-488e-82da-53bb586cd23b.c000.json
```

And the MSFT file looks like this:

```
{"values":{"MSFT":{"1388534400":55,"1388620800":55}}}
```

While the "values" column name may not be in your dictionary structure, I hope this illustrates what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Spark 2.3.1`
This is `PySpark` version -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,collect_list,create_map
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType,IntegerType,StringType

myValues = [('1388534400', 'GOOG', 50), ('1388534400', 'FB', 60), ('1388534400', 'MSFT', 55), ('1388620800', 'GOOG', 52),
('1388620800', 'FB', 61), ('1388620800', 'MSFT', 55)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myValues,['date','stock','price'])
df.show()
+----------+-----+-----+
|      date|stock|price|
+----------+-----+-----+
|1388534400| GOOG|   50|
|1388534400|   FB|   60|
|1388534400| MSFT|   55|
|1388620800| GOOG|   52|
|1388620800|   FB|   61|
|1388620800| MSFT|   55|
+----------+-----+-----+

combineMap = udf(lambda maps: {key:f[key] for f in maps for key in f},
             MapType(StringType(),IntegerType()))

combineDeepMap = udf(lambda maps: {key:f[key] for f in maps for key in f},
             MapType(StringType(),MapType(StringType(),IntegerType())))

mapdf = df.groupBy('stock')\
.agg(collect_list(create_map('date','price')).alias('maps'))\
.agg(combineDeepMap(collect_list(create_map('stock',combineMap('maps')))))

new_dict= mapdf.collect()[0][0]
print(new_dict)
   {u'GOOG': {u'1388620800': 52, u'1388534400': 50}, u'FB': {u'1388620800': 61, u'1388534400': 60}, u'MSFT': {u'1388620800': 55, u'1388534400': 55}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting `ImportError: cannot import name create_map` during the import. I'm on Spark 1.6.0/Python 2.7