# Split Pyspark dataframe into multiple json files based on a particular column data?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following json of format:

```
{"year":"2020", "id":"1", "fruit":"Apple","cost": "100" }
{"year":"2020", "id":"2", "fruit":"Kiwi", "cost": "200"}
{"year":"2020", "id":"3", "fruit":"Cherry", "cost": "300"}
{"year":"2020", "id":"4", "fruit": "Apple","cost": "400" }
{"year":"2020", "id":"5", "fruit": "Mango", "cost": "500"}
{"year":"2020", "id":"6", "fruit": "Kiwi", "cost": "600"}
```

Its of type: `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`

How can I split this json file into multiple json files and save it in a `year` directory using `Pyspark`? like:

directory: `path.../2020/<all split json files>`

`Apple.json`

```
{"year":"2020", "id":"1", "fruit":"Apple","cost": "100" }
{"year":"2020", "id":"4", "fruit": "Apple","cost": "400" }
```

`Kiwi.json`

```
{"year":"2020", "id":"2", "fruit":"Kiwi", "cost": "200"}
{"year":"2020", "id":"6", "fruit": "Kiwi", "cost": "600"}
```

`Mango.json`

```
{"year":"2020", "id":"5", "fruit": "Mango", "cost": "500"}
```

`Cherry.json`

```
{"year":"2020", "id":"3", "fruit":"Cherry", "cost": "300"}
```

Also if I encounter a different year, how do push the files in similar way like: `path.../2021/<all split json files>` ?

Initially I tried, finding all the unique fruits and create a list. Then tried creating multiple data frames & pushing the json values into it. Then converted every dataframe into a json format. But I find this inefficient.
Then I also checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53925954/pyspark-create-multiple-json-files-from-dataframe?noredirect=1&lq=1). But issue here is it creates a key value pair in dict form, which is slightly different.

Then I also learned about Pyspark groupBy method. It seems to make sense because I could groupBy() the fruit values and then split the json file, but I feel I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following JSON as an example

```
{"year":"2020", "id":"1", "fruit":"Apple","cost": "100" }
{"year":"2020", "id":"2", "fruit":"Kiwi", "cost": "200"}
{"year":"2020", "id":"3", "fruit":"Cherry", "cost": "300"}
{"year":"2021", "id":"10", "fruit": "Pear","cost": "1000" }
{"year":"2021", "id":"11", "fruit": "Mango", "cost": "1100"}
{"year":"2021", "id":"12", "fruit": "Banana", "cost": "1200"}
```

You can use `partitionBy` to partion the data by `year` and `fruit`. Note that I created a duplicate of the year column as the column that you partition on is dropped when you write the data to disk.

```
df = spark.read.json("./ex.json")
df = df.withColumn("Year", df["year"])
df = df.withColumn("Fruit", df["fruit"])
df.write.partitionBy("Year", "Fruit").json("result")
```

This results in a folder called `RESULT` with the following structure.

```
|-- RESULT
|   |-- Year=2020
|   |   |-- Fruit=Apple
|   |   |   |-- part0000-dcea0683...json
|   |   |-- Fruit=Cherry
|   |   |   |-- part0000-dcea0683...json
|   |   |-- Fruit=Kiwi
|   |   |   |-- part0000-dcea0683...json
|   |-- Year=2021
|   |   |-- Fruit=Banana
|   |   |   |-- part0000-dcea0683...json
|   |   |-- Fruit=Mango
|   |   |   |-- part0000-dcea0683...json
|   |   |-- Fruit=Pear
|   |   |   |-- part0000-dcea0683...json
```

Comment: Thank you very much.